# Installing build dependencies ...Error while installing pyInstaller using pip

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

Python version -3.7

I tried installing pyInstaller using pip.
I get the following output and error message in cmd.

Error message

```
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached pyinstaller-4.0.tar.gz (3.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-d_vuoc7m\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (14 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 5, in <module>
      import locale
    File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\locale.py", line 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line 143, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-d_vuoc7m\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Did you call anything `enum` in your project?

Comment: I don't know about that. I only used the usual command, python -m pip install pyinstaller in command prompt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+%27enum%27+has+no+attribute+IntFlag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `pip uninstall enum34` and run the command again.

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as the correct one ( the green check mark)